# Strange excel copy/paste behavior

Tags: microsoft-excel

My spreadsheet (in Excel online) produces the following behavior when copying the formula "=max(A2,2)" from cell B2:

[image: 2]

You can see that Excel has adjusted the reference from A2 to A3 correctly in the pasted formula, but it seems to have copied the value from B2 to B3 instead of evaluating the adjusted formula.

If I enter the formula "=max(a3,2)" manually, I get the expected behavior:

[image: 3]

This spreadsheet was obtained by deleting data from a more complicated spreadsheet where I first noticed the problem. Entering the same data in a new spreadsheet does not reproduce the anomalous behavior.

How can I get copy/paste to behave as expected again in the original spreadsheet?

Comment: It looks like manual calculation. Are you sure that automatic calculation is enabled?